# Search using Google Places API - Flutter

Tags: rest, google-maps, flutter, google-places-api

Is there any way to use Google places API's search functionality (without using flutter_google_places and flutter_google_places_autocomplete)? I found [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4466319-google-maps-for-flutter-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-011) that shows nearby places, but doesn't have anything for manual search.

The searchbar offered with flutter_google_places is basic, so what should I do to implement that same functionality in a custom designed searbar?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search and https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro for overview

Comment: I looked at that, but it just confused me more. Is there any example of how to use that? I specifically mean a modified searchbar for places search.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses

Comment: Thanks for that, but I meant an example in Flutter

Comment: if you dont know how to get some data from the internet using flutter read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!